# Swift : how to check which view is causing constraints error

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I am getting the following error when trying to load a VC:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "Unable to activate constraint with anchors 
<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x280fea300 \"i6.I6FuelSheetTextField:0x1030fe400.centerX\"> and 
<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x280fea440 
\"UILayoutGuide:0x282327800'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.centerX\"> because they have no common 
ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  
That's illegal."
```

How can I identify which views these addresses are referring to?

Comment: If you can't identify the views with the error messages (such as `FuelSheetTextField` in the message you've shown), you may find it helpful to try using [exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1526934-exerciseambiguityinlayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because you are trying to constraint two views that are unrelated to each other. You are lucky enough to get enough information from the error. You are using a component that an instance of `I6FuelSheetTextField` and you trying to constraint it's `centerX` attribute. So, I think the error itself is pretty explanatory.

Note: It could also be the case when you forget to add a view to another view's subview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My issue is there are a lot of instances of these textfields in the viewController and I wondered whether I could identify specifically which one is causing the issue from the memory addresses

Comment: From the crash, you could trace it back to the source. You could find the class and function name that cause this. You just need to look carefully in the crash log.